# Linq check if null and send to razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing my first MVC application, in it I am using Linq to query my DB.

I am having trouble with the query below.

```
indexModel.MostValuablePurchased = (from purch in db.Purchases
                            where purch.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                             && purch.DateBought.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                             orderby purch.Price descending
                             select purch.TagNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

For users with data it performs as expected. But when the query returns null it crashes when it gets to the razor view with the error "Value cannot be null or empty."

What is the best way to handle this situation. 
Thanks

Comment: Where exactly does it throw an exception? Is there any more information within it? What is `indexModel`?

Comment: So could you show the Razor part where the crash happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all down the the business rules for your application and the data, and you could handle it in code, or in the view. It's important to remember the benefits of the MVC design pattern, and with this in mind you may not want to handle it in the view so that the business logic is decoupled from the presentation of the data.

For example, one way is to create a variable to hold the value of your query:

```
var mostValuablePurchased = (from purch in db.Purchases
                                            where purch.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && purch.DateBought.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                                            orderby purch.Price descending
                                            select purch.TagNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then set your model value appropriately

```
indexModel.MostValuablePurchased = mostValuablePurchased ?? 0;
```

Obviously you will want to need to substitute the 0 for whatever default value you need if the query is null. This example is assuming you want to display a default value, and that MostValuablePurchased is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
if (WebSecurity.CurrentUserId!=null){

indexModel.MostValuablePurchased = db.Purchases.Where(o => o.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && o.DateBought!=null && o.DateBought.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year && o.TagNo!=null).Max(o=>o.Price).TagNo;}
```